Is there any way we can hide the forgot password link in supabase auth ui?
I want to hide the forgot password link that appears when we use supabase auth ui
I am aware of the hide links property and perhaps I could have used that but that hides other links as well, I just want to hide the forgot password link

There is no way to hide individual links with the Supabase AuthUI library. It's all or none.
